# Unable to instantiate activity | Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting this error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.demo.gandharv.exkotlin, PID: 7742
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.pantelwar.gandharv.scobokotlin/com.demo.gandharv.exkotlin.RegisterActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3095)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                      Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>                                                                                         at com.demo.gandharv.exkotlin.RegisterActivity.(RegisterActivity.kt:12)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3085)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

I have defined the **RegisterActivity** in my **AndroidMenifest.xml**.

I have no idea why i'm getting this error.

Here's my LoginActivity.kt

```
package com.demo.gandharv.exkotlin

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var email: String = ""
var password: String = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    loginButton.setOnClickListener {
        email = emailEditText.text.toString()
        password = passwordEditText.text.toString()
    }

    registerTextView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably a property defined as non-nullable having null value at access time. Please post your activity code.

Comment: I've pasted my activity. have a look

Comment: Post RegisterActivity. From the stack trace it's obvious that NPE occured there on line 12.

Comment: @Harv did you manage to solve this?

Comment: As @MarošŠeleng says, post **RegisterActivity** class